# Function to restart a counter variable at zero when it is greater than an array's length -- not working

Tags: javascript, control-flow

I am a novice developer trying to build an image carousel with html, css and javascript.

I have an array of images called 'slides' and variables called currentSlide, prevSlide, nextSlide that I want to use to keep track of the relevant slide index so that I can later display the proper slide as the values for the variables update.

I am trying to make it so the following will happen when the user clicks 'NEXT':

- event listener calls a function called slideRight
- slideRight will call 2 functions: updateVarsRight and displaySlides

  - updateVarsRight will increment the variables (ex. currentSlide) by 1 
    and then call another function called enforceLoop.

    - enforceLoop() will make sure the incremented variable values 
      do not move outside of the corresponding image array values. (i.e. 
       when currentSlide > slides.length-1, currentSlide = 0).
  - displaySlides will of course, display the new slides

The problem im having is with the enforceLoop function. If i check the console and click next, it seems that when currentSlide 's value is incremented past the total amount of slide in the array and is supposed to be set back to zero, it doesn't and continues to count upward.

It's hard for me to articulate but if you are able to run the codepen and check the console as you click next it should be clear what I mean.

I'm sure there are much better more efficient ways to build a slideshow but I was trying to figure things out on my own and this is the strategy I decided to go with and then look at refactoring afterwards.

Apologies if i haven't explained the issue clearly enough, first time poster.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/dansoutar/pen/RXZREV

Main issue:

```
function enforceLoop(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    num === slides.length - 1;
    console.log('num is now the last slide...' + num);
    return num;
  } else if (num > slides.length - 1) {
    num === 0;
    console.log(num + '...should be zero!!');
    return num;
  } else {
    console.log('enforce loop = num is ...' + num);
    return num;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, `===` is used for equality checking, so your lines at the beginning of each `if` case compare num to `slides.length - 1` and `0` respectively; they do not assign to `num`. Change `===` for `=` in both of these places and `enforceLoop` should work correctly.

Corrected code:

```
function enforceLoop(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    num = slides.length - 1;
    console.log('num is now the last slide...' + num);
    return num;
  } else if (num > slides.length - 1) {
    num = 0;
    console.log(num + '...should be zero!!');
    return num;
  } else {
    console.log('enforce loop = num is ...' + num);
    return num;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

`num === slides.length - 1;`, `num === 0;`

`===` is an equality operator. You want to use the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Wow, should've realized that. Thank you.